# How can I add and update contacts?

Tags: java, android

I try to add new contact from database or update exiting contact (order by number and update name and address).

I make something like this:

```
    public void WritePhoneContact(String displayName, String number, String address,Context cntx)
{
    Context contetx     = cntx; 
    String strDisplayName   =  displayName; 
    String strNumber    =  number; 
    String strAddress = address;

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> cntProOper = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    int contactIndex = cntProOper.size();

    Uri numberUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL, Uri.encode(number));

    Cursor numberCursor = contetx.getContentResolver().query(numberUri, null, null, null, null);

    if (numberCursor != null && numberCursor.moveToFirst()) {

        cntProOper.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(Phone.NUMBER,new String[]{number})
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null).build());


        cntProOper.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(Phone.NUMBER,new String[]{number})
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, strDisplayName) 
                .build());


        cntProOper.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(Phone.NUMBER,new String[]{number})
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, strNumber)
                .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE).build()); 



        cntProOper.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(Phone.NUMBER,new String[]{number})
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS, strAddress).build());
    } else {
        cntProOper.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null).build());


        cntProOper.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, strDisplayName)
                .build());


        cntProOper.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, strNumber)
                .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE).build());



        cntProOper.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS, strAddress).build());
    }




    try
    {
        // We will do batch operation to insert all above data
        //Contains the output of the app of a ContentProviderOperation.
        //It is sure to have exactly one of uri or count set
        ContentProviderResult[] contentProresult = null;
        contentProresult = contetx.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, cntProOper); //apply above data insertion into contacts list
    }
    catch (RemoteException exp)
    {
        //logs;
    }
    catch (OperationApplicationException exp)
    {
        //logs
    }
}
```

but updating doesn't work well. I think thats is something wrong with ordering and selection.

Comment: "updating doesn't work well" ... that's one of the worst error descriptions I heard in quite a while ... Please state clearly 1. What do you expect to happen, 2. What happens actually, 3. What have you found out so far.

Comment: I'm sorry, English is not my native language. At the time of call, the application retrieves data from the database and the application looks-if the contact is not in the phone book, the record is added. If a contact is in a phone book, the contact's name and address changes to those in the database.

Comment: Your English is good. Just "does not work well" doesn't give us the information needed to help you :)

Comment: What you describe in the comment is the expected behavior, right? Now, which part does not work as expected and how?

Comment: Thanks! I have a trouble with a first part, where I updating my exiting contact.

cntProOper.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(Phone.NUMBER,new String[]{number})
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null).build());

I think that it isn't right structure.